# ApiPlatform - create custom endpoint

Tags: php, api-platform.com, symfony5

I try to create a `search` endpoint using api platform.
Client should send search query throught SearchInput::class (serialization), then I would use elasticSearch to perform search on another entity, add my own logic and use SearchOutput::class as Response (deserialization).

That entity is not related to the database so I use DTO

I followed the documentation https://api-platform.com/docs/core/controllers/ but I'm actually facing the following error

`The controller for URI \"/api/search\" is not callable: Controller \"PostSearchController\" does neither exist as service nor as class.`

Message is very explicit but I can't figure out why it happen and how resolve it.

App\Entity\Search.php

```php
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use App\Controller\PostSearchController;
use App\Dto\SearchInput;
use App\Dto\SearchOutput;

/**
 * @ApiResource(
 *   input=SearchInput::class,
 *   output=SearchOutput::class,
 *   collectionOperations = {
 *     "search" = {
 *       "method" = "POST",
 *       "path" = "/search",
 *       "controller" = "PostSearchController::class"
 *     }
 *  },
 *  itemOperations = {
 *
 *  }
 * )
 */
final class Search
{
    public $id;
}
```

App\Controller\PostSearchController.php

```php
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\Search;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;

class PostSearchController extends AbstractController
{
    public function __invoke(Search $data): Search
    {
        var_dump($data);die;
    }
}
```

symfony debug:router

```sh
-------------------------------- -------- -------- ------ ------------------------------------- 
  Name                             Method   Scheme   Host   Path                                 
 -------------------------------- -------- -------- ------ ------------------------------------- 
  _wdt                             ANY      ANY      ANY    /_wdt/{token}                        
  _profiler_home                   ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/                          
  _profiler_search                 ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/search                    
  _profiler_search_bar             ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/search_bar                
  _profiler_phpinfo                ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/phpinfo                   
  _profiler_search_results         ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}/search/results    
  _profiler_open_file              ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/open                      
  _profiler                        ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}                   
  _profiler_router                 ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}/router            
  _profiler_exception              ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}/exception         
  _profiler_exception_css          ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}/exception.css     
  api_entrypoint                   ANY      ANY      ANY    /api/{index}.{_format}               
  api_doc                          ANY      ANY      ANY    /api/docs.{_format}                  
  api_jsonld_context               ANY      ANY      ANY    /api/contexts/{shortName}.{_format}  
  api_searches_search_collection   POST     ANY      ANY    /api/search                          
  api_photos_get_item              GET      ANY      ANY    /api/photos/{id}.{_format}           
  _preview_error                   ANY      ANY      ANY    /_error/{code}.{_format}             
  api_login_check                  ANY      ANY      ANY    /api/login_check                     
 -------------------------------- -------- -------- ------ -------------------------------------
```

symfony debug:container

```sh
Select one of the following services to display its information:
  [0] App\Controller\PostSearchController
  [1] App\Dto\SearchInput
  [2] App\Dto\SearchOutput
  [3] disallow_search_engine_index_response_listener
  [4] api_platform.doctrine.orm.search_filter
  [5] annotated_app_entity_photo_api_platform_core_bridge_doctrine_orm_filter_search_filter
  [6] ApiPlatform\Core\Bridge\Doctrine\Orm\Filter\SearchFilter
 > 0


Information for Service "App\Controller\PostSearchController"
=============================================================

 ---------------- ------------------------------------- 
  Option           Value                                
 ---------------- ------------------------------------- 
  Service ID       App\Controller\PostSearchController  
  Class            App\Controller\PostSearchController  
  Tags             controller.service_arguments         
                   container.service_subscriber         
  Calls            setContainer                         
  Public           yes                                  
  Synthetic        no                                   
  Lazy             no                                   
  Shared           yes                                  
  Abstract         no                                   
  Autowired        yes                                  
  Autoconfigured   yes                                  
 ---------------- -------------------------------------
```

[image]

Comment: Just checking the easy things first: You're sure the value `"/search"` passed as the `path` value will be interpreted relative to **/api**?

Comment: No I'm not I tried `/search`, `search` and `/api/search` without succes. `symfony debug:router` show that route is enable and `symfony debug:container` show SearchPostController as service.

Comment: I checked it and seems to be interpreted correctly according profiler see screenshot

Comment: use the FQCN for your controller. `App\Controller\PostSearchController` in the annotation. The import would work if you used attributes, but I don't think it would for annotations.

Comment: @yivi that's works it' s weird because `input=SearchInput::class` works...

Comment: Glad you solved it. Reading the error message carefully was all that was needed. See that the error message does not include the fully qualified name.

Comment: @yivi Relative classname works fine with `@ApiResource`. @akio I guess you should remove the double quotes wrapping your `controller` name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @yivi for the help

Solution is to use the FQCN in ApiResource annotation

```php
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;

/**
 * @ApiResource(
 *   input="App\Dto\SearchInput",
 *   output="App\Dto\SearchOutput",
 *   collectionOperations = {
 *     "search" = {
 *       "method" = "post",
 *       "path" = "/search",
 *       "controller" = "App\Controller\PostSearchController"
 *     }
 *  },
 *  itemOperations = {
 *
 *  }
 * )
 */
final class Search
{
    public $id;
}
```